# Composition of non-Bijections is a Bijection

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

**Setup:**

Let $f,g$ be composable maps.  Then it's clear that $g\circ f:X\to Y$ is a bijection, where $X,Y$ are just some sets.  However, it also seems that non-bijections can compose to a bijection...

**Funny Example (Haha):**

For example, let fix $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and define
$$
\begin{aligned}
f:\mathbb{R} &\to \mathbb{R}^2\\
x &\to (x,a)
\end{aligned},
$$
let $g$ be the map
$$
\begin{aligned}
g:\mathbb{R}^2 &\to \mathbb{R}\\
(x,y) &\to x+y
\end{aligned}.
$$
Clearly $g$ is surjective but not injective and $f$ is injective but not surjective...but $g\circ f(x)=x+a$ which is a bijection!

**Question:**

In general, are there necessary and sufficient conditions on $f,g$ for $g\circ f$ to be a bijection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!

For an application $h:X \to Y$, let $h_{|A}$ denote the restriction of $h$ over $A\subset X$, i.e. $h_{|A} : A \to Y \quad;\quad x \mapsto h(x)$

We need the following equivalences :

$g\circ f$ is surjective (resp. injective) $\iff$ $g_{|f(X)}$ is surjective (resp. $f$ and $g_{|f(X)}$ are injective).

For example, let's show the first equivalence:

\begin{align}
g\circ f \text{ is surjective} &\iff \forall y \in Y, \exists x \in X \mid g\circ f(x) = y\\
& \iff \forall y \in Y, \exists x' \in f(X) \mid g(x') = y \\
& \iff g_{|f(X)} \text{ is surjective}
\end{align}

And for the second one, remark that if $f$ is non-injective, $g\circ f$ cannot be injective. So $f$ has to be injective. But then it still can happen that $x\neq y \in X$  and $g\circ f(x) = g\circ f(y)$ (if $g$ is a constant map for example). So, you can show $g_{|f(X)}$ has to be injective to (supposing that it is not will lead you to a contradiction). Finally, it is easy to show that these necessary conditions are sufficient.